# During creating new app in ArgoCD, ArgoCD can't detect private git repository path

Tags: kubernetes, argocd, kind

During creating new app in ArgoCD, ArgoCD can't detect in private git repository path( but can connect and show all branches )
Repository connection status is successfully connected.
Provided all authentication credentials. token (https) and ssh (ssh-key)
ArgoCD can detect git branches bu can't detect path to helm chart.

ArgoCD running on kind

Provided all keys and tokens, tried https and ssh.

Comment: What do you mean by it cannot detect path?

Comment: After adding repository link to app configuration. ArgoCD detect which branches this repo have. (So it is mean that argocd successfully connected to repo ), but after it argocd can not detect path to helm chart in git repository. 

It is looks like argocd ( forever loading the path )

Comment: Maybe share your App or Appset definition, which error you get, screenshot.. otherwise hard to help.